# Set ufw rules as a oneliner

Tags: ufw

This is how I setup my ufw rules:

```
$ sudo ufw default deny
$ sudo ufw allow ssh
$ sudo ufw allow http
$ sudo ufw allow https
$ sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
$ sudo ufw allow 53/udp
$ sudo ufw allow from any port 68 to any port 67 proto udp
```

Is it possible to get a oneliner for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write it as

```
sudo ufw default deny & sudo ufw allow ssh & sudo ufw allow http & sudo ufw allow https & sudo ufw allow 53/tcp & sudo ufw allow 53/udp & sudo ufw allow from any port 68 to any port 67 proto udp
```

seperating the commands by `&`.

---

Anyway more beautiful would be writing a script
E.g. in ~/setUp_UFW.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo ufw default deny l
sudo ufw allow ssh
sudo ufw allow http
sudo ufw allow https
sudo ufw allow 53/tcp
sudo ufw allow 53/udp
sudo ufw allow from any port 68 to any port 67 proto udp
```

Make the script executable

```
chmod +x ~/setUp_UFW.sh
```

than everytime you just go

```
~/setUp_UFW.sh
```

to set it up.
(You will be asked for the sudo password when the script sees sudo the first time.)

Comment: How would I prevent output for this part of the bash script?

Comment: To not write output of a command to stdout in bash end each line with ` &> /dev/null` or wrap the whole script as further explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18063720/7111561)